# How to access game object from scene class?

Tags: object, phaser-framework

How

in the body of a function,

that is a member scene object class,

that is listed as a value in the game object config,

```
const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
     scene: MainScene,
     ...
```

would I get a reference to the game object,

if I wanted to do something like get values from pointer the like this:

```
export class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
private foo;

constructor() {
    super({ key: "MainScene" });

    this.foo = game.input.mousePointer;
}
```

assuming that the scene and game object are in different ts files

?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the game object in any scene using `this.sys.game`. This will not be available in a scene's constructor, though. You should move scene setup to the `init` function, which will be called automatically by the framework when the game object is available.

With this change your example would look like this:

```
export class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  private foo;

  constructor() {
    super({ key: "MainScene" });
  }

  init() {
    this.foo = this.sys.game.input.mousePointer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(MainScene);` and combing through that. I'm not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish?